# iTunes Connect Users & Roles for limited app access

Tags: app-store-connect

Let's say I have a developer account under ‘agent’ and I have 3 other companies that are helping build Apple apps for me.

As for the role access, is it possible for me to limit this *Company A* to only allow him to see *Application A* that he help build under iTunes Connect?  The same goes for *Company B*, to only allow them to see *Application B* apps they're helping me to build?

I'm a bit confused as to which role should I select from [iTunes Connect FAQ: What user roles are available on iTunes Connect and which permissions does each user role have?](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are four roles you can grant to the users for them to access all the data about specific apps:

> **App Manager**: The App Managers can edit all aspects of the apps they have access to, and can add users to those apps. These users can be granted limited app access.
>
> **Developer**: The Developer user has access to My Apps and Resources and Help. They can upload binaries to iTunes Connect and manage internal TestFlight users. These users can be granted limited app access.
>
> **Marketer**: The Marketer role is for users who manage marketing materials and promotional artwork. Users with the Marketing role will be contacted by the App Store team if an app is chosen to be featured on the App Store. They can update app metadata and request promo codes from My Apps. These users can be granted limited app access.
>
> **Sales**: The Sales role has access to Sales and Trends, and iTunes Connect for iOS. They can only download the full sales reports if they also have the Reports role. Sales users can be granted limited app access.

<sup>https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview</sup>

All of these roles support limited app access, which is the ability to restrict accounts to only view certain apps. Granting Admin or Finance automatically provides the ability to see every app associated with the developer program membership.

You can configure limited app access…

- when creating a new app

  > If you choose to limit access to the app, users whose roles can be limited and who are not selected will not be able to see the app in iTunes Connect. Users with the Admin, Technical, Finance or Reports role cannot have limited app access, so they will see all apps. If you do not select any users in the Limit User Access section, everyone will have access to the app.

  <sup>https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html</sup>
- from iTunes Connect Users & Roles

  > **To limit a user’s access to certain apps:**
  >
  > 1. In the Users and Roles pane, select the user you want to edit by clicking on their Apple ID.
  > 2. Select the Roles pane.
  > 3. Under the Apps dropdown select the apps to which this user should be limited.
  > 4. Click Save.
  >
  >    [image]

  <sup>https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html</sup>

Comment: For more brief role permissions in tabular format, visit: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve5f9a89d7

Comment: the user is limited to this app in analytics only. Not in Sales and Trends